# How to input a number between two numbers that allow for text to be written after

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is part of the code I am making, I am trying to make the user input a number to choose which level they want to do from 1-100 but when they put a number it tells them which overall level that they are in. I have used this code but I can't seem to make it work. The conditions are that it can't break if a number below, above or text is entered, it should just re-ask the question.

```
#Ask for level 
Level = ""  

#make code for it
def number():

    while True:
        try:
            Level = int(input("What is the level in the game? "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number")
        else:
            break

        return Level

    while True:
        if number <=25:
            print ("Beginner" )

        if number >=26 and number <=75:
            print ("Intermediate")

        if number >=76 and number <=100:
            print ("expert")

        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not making a call to the `number()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You exit from loop 1 but stuck in another `while` loop. In the second loop you have used `number` as variable while its defniend as function so should be used as `number()`
Try this simplified code.

```
#make code for it
def number():
    while True:
        try:
            Level = int(input("What is the level in the game? "))

            if Level <= 25:
                print ("Beginner" )
                break

            elif Level >=26 and Level <=75:
                print ("Intermediate")
                break

            elif Level >=76 and Level <=100:
                print ("expert")
                break
            else:
                print("Out Of range(1-100): Please enter a valid number:")

        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number")

 return Level

num = number()  # If you really want to print/get the value entered
```

If you want to keep condition out of main method. Than do this but remember in any case 2nd `while` loop is not needed at all.

```
#make code for it
def number():
    Level = 0

    while True:
        try:
            Level = int(input("What is the level in the game? "))

            if not 1 <= Level <= 100:
                print("Out Of range(1-100): Please enter a valid number:")
            else:
                break

        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number")

    return Level

num = number()
if num <=25:
    print ("Beginner" )

if num >=26 and number <=75:
    print ("Intermediate")

if num >=76 and number <=100:
    print ("expert")
```

Comment: the second one breaks when a higher number is entered, by any chance do you know how to fix that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def number():
  while True:
    num = input('"What is the level in the game? ')

    try:
      val = int(num)
      if val <=25:
        print ("Beginner" )
        break
      if val >=26 and val <=75:
        print ("Intermediate")
        break
      if val >=76 and val <=100:
        print ("expert")
        break
      if val >100:
        print("Out Of range(1-100): Please enter a valid number")
    except ValueError:
      print("Please enter a valid number")

number = number()
```

Comment: how do i make it stop after they have answered once?

Answer (score 0):

Since your full code is not displayed, i'm making some assumptions

1> You have replaced the value of Level  in number.

2> You are actually calling number(), and is replacing the variable number with Level

3>Assuming you have no code to place the Level returned above to number, i'm replacing number with Level

```
def number():
    while True:
        try:
            Level = int(input("What is the level in the game? "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number")
        else:
            break
        if Level > 1:
            return Level
    while True:
        if Level <= 25:
            print("Beginner")
            break
        if Level >= 26 and Level <= 75:
            print("Intermediate")
            break
        if Level >= 76 and Level <= 100:
            print("expert")
            break
```